# Embedding a cmap in moinmoin

Tags: administration, html

I'd like to embed a cmap in a [moinmoin](http://moinmo.in/) wiki page. I generated the cmap using [dia](https://live.gnome.org/Dia).

I then copy pasted the generated [html code](http://pastebin.com/YFXgGT0S), modified it to point to the png image I attached to the wiki. However when saving the whole map section disappears from the code.

Does anyone has a pointer for me? Has someone already managed to use a cmap in MoinMoin?

PS: not sure it's the correct forum for asking this, don't hesitate to point me somewhere else if not.

Comment: The best place for questions like this is probably an application-specific support channel, [have a look here](http://moinmo.in/Support) (there's [the MoinMoin project's chatroom](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinChat) and a [mailing list](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinMailingLists)).

Comment: OK thanks. Sorry about that, I asked the question on their chatroom, thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

There's no use in modifying the html code in the GUI editor: when saving it it is then translated into MoinMoin syntax. The html code is accessible only for the GUI to be a wysiwyg. There's no existing clickable image in MoinMoin.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://moinmo.in/ActionMarket/VisualSiteMap) could be useful... their "VisualSiteMap" is a cmap, after all... (so you might need your own custom plugin that directly writes the html via `request.write(...)`, but I'm guessing wildly here.)